# How to capture values in a string using regex in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Below I have a sample of a log file that I am working with:

```
5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.
```

Almost every line is like this, but some will say Savings not found. Below is the most important part of this  sample:

```
Savings found: $257.18
```

I am trying to write a piece of code that will look through this log file, search through the whole file, and if savings were found, it will record that number into a variable, that way when I total it up, it will just fall into a variable.

The problem I am having right now is getting my code to display just that number. Below is what I have been working on thus far:

```
foreach (string line in gdsGroup)
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"Savings\s+found:\s*\$(?<savings>\d+\.\d+)\s*\(\s*(?<percent>\d+\.\d+)\s*%");
            if (m.Success)
            {
                decimal gdsNumberSavings = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["savings"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                decimal gdsNumberPercent = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["percent"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                string prefix = string.Empty;

                if (gdsNumberPercent >= 30)
                {
                    if (gdsNumberSavings >= 500)
                        prefix = "**";
                    else
                        prefix = "*";
                }
                Console.WriteLine(prefix + line + "\n");
                Console.WriteLine(gdsNumberSavings);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem that is happening is that after the line that gives me what I have above, it prints out the of the savings for that line. So my question is, should I continue to try to go about a variable way, or do I need a regular expression to isolate that value, and if I need a regular expression what would the expression be?

Comment: "The problem I am having right now is getting my code to display just that number?  What is "THAT" number?

Comment: @Shar1er80 the savings found is that number. So in the sample I provided, that $257.18 is an example of that number, minus the dollar sign of course

Comment: And what do you want to do with that number? You've already successfully obtained it with the Regex you're using.

Comment: I want that to be added to the other numbers in the log file. For example: if I were to run this program, at the end of my program I would want it to say "the total savings I found were: " and the blank space being the total number it finds

Comment: So if I had  that sample number twice in this file, and those were the only savings found, it would say "The total savings found were: 514.36"

Comment: I thought I had obtained it, but when I run the program it gives me that total at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the Regex you are using to obtain the value you are wanting from each line in your `foreach`.

You just need an accumulator initialized before you start the `foreach` and add `gdsNumberSavings` to it whenever there is a match.

```
string[] lines = 
{
    "5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.",
    "5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.",
    "5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found.",
    "5/21/2015 11:55:56 PM | Batch 6|386/767|50.33 %|CH2M-R|Processed NXRMN5...Checking refundable and non-refundable fares. Traditional Booking. Inside ticketing window. Minimum Savings Required: $131.00. Actual Savings: $257.18. Savings found: $257.18 (11.55 %). Savings were previously found."
};

// Initialize total
decimal total = 0;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"Savings\s+found:\s*\$(?<savings>\d+\.\d+)\s*\(\s*(?<percent>\d+\.\d+)\s*%");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        decimal gdsNumberSavings = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["savings"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        decimal gdsNumberPercent = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["percent"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string prefix = string.Empty;

        if (gdsNumberPercent >= 30)
        {
            prefix = gdsNumberSavings >= 500 ? "**" : "*";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(prefix + line + "\n");
        Console.WriteLine(gdsNumberSavings);

        // Accumulate into a total
        total += gdsNumberSavings;
    }
}
// Display total
Console.WriteLine("Total Savings: {0}", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as for the variable side of the question. But as for the regular expression, this will find your dollar amounts: `\$[0-9]+[.]\d{2}`
You have three dollar amounts in that line, so just take the second instance that would be returned from the expression and that would be your total savings.

Comment: Could you go a little farther in depth as to what you mean by second instance?

Comment: When a regular expression is used, it will return everything in the string that matches the expression (starting from the beginning). In your sample string that you gave, the expression will have three matches (the three different dollar amounts). So you use the second match returned for your total savings.